# How to fill a closure table using JPA?

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa

I am trying to model a hierarchy of objects (actually, domain groups) in a database. I decided to use a closure table, so that I can gain high flexibility in querying the hierarchy. Basically, my schema looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE group (
    id INT -- primary key
    ... -- other fields here
)

CREATE TABLE groupHierarchy (
    idAncestor INT,
    idGroup INT,
    hierarchyLevel INT
)
```

So, when a group with an id of 1 contains a group with an id of 2, which in turn contains a group with an id of 3, I will need to have following rows in the groupHierarchy table.

```
idAncestor  idGroup  hierarchyLevel
1           1             0
2           2             0
3           3             0
1           2             1
2           3             1
1           3             2
```

I am also OK with not having the rows with the hierarchyLevels of 0 (self - reference).

Now I would like to have an JPA entity that would map to the group table. My question is - what would be a good way to manage the groupHierarchy table?

What I already considered is:

1) Having the group hierarchy mapped as an element collection, like :

```
@ElementCollection
@JoinTable(name = "groupHierarchy")
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "idAncestor")
@Column(name = "hierarchyLevel")
Map<Group, Integer> ancestors;
```

This would require handling the hierarchy entirely in the application, and I am afraid that this may become very complex.

2) Make the application unaware of the hierarchyLevel column and handle it in the database using a trigger (when a record is added, check if the parent already has ancestors and if so, add any other required rows. This is also where the hierarchyLevel of 0 would come in handy). It seems to me that the database trigger would be simpler, but I'm not sure if that would be good for the overall readability.

Can anyone suggest other options? Or maybe point to any pros or cons of the solutions I have mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest you using [JpaTreeDao](http://members.chello.at/fritz.ritzberger/downloads/jpatreedao/JpaTreeDao.html)? I think it's complete and very well documented. I'm going to try to port the closure tables code to a groovy implementation...